# Lost reference to object after deserialization

Tags: java

Suppose I have two `HashMap`s: `hashMapFoo` and `hashMapBar`.

I create some object `objCake` and `put` it into both maps, so each map has a reference to `objCake`, and when I make some changes to `objCake` whichever map I access it from, I get correct state of my object.

After I serialize both maps and deserialize them, I meet problem that my object `objCake` has become two different objects! I change its state in `hashMapFoo`, but nothing happens in `hashMapBar`. `hashMapBar` does not contain the correct reference any more!
All maps and objects `implement Serializable`.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me:

```
public class MapSerializationTest {
    private static class Foo implements Serializable {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Map<String, Foo> map1 = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
        map1.put("foo", foo);
        Map<String, Foo> map2 = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
        map2.put("foo", foo);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(map1);
        oos.writeObject(map2);
        oos.close();

        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        map1 = (Map<String, Foo>) ois.readObject();
        map2 = (Map<String, Foo>) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(map1.get("foo") == map2.get("foo")); // prints true
    }
}
```

Show us your code. You probably call `reset()` on the ObjectOutputStream between the first and the second map. Or you use two difference ObjectOutputStream instances.

Comment: @JB Nizet, you're right. I use different intances of OOStr <code>public void saveVessels(){
  try {
   ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(VESSEL_FILE));
   os.writeObject(vesselList);
   os.close();
  }catch (Exception ex){
   timePlanner.displayMessage("Failed to save vessels!");
  }
 }

 public void saveCategories(){
  try {
   ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(CATEGORIES_FILE));
   os.writeObject(categoryList);
   os.close();
  }catch (Exception ex){
   timePlanner.displayMessage("Could not save categories!");
  }
 } </code>

Answer (score 4):

You can use a container for both your HashMaps, so that they both belong to the same object graph, otherwise, when the object graph is recreated, Java has no way to determine that they are the same object. After all, you serialize them and deserialize them independently, isn't so?

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
   private Map<Object, Object> hashMapFoo ;
   private Map<Object, Object> hashMapBar;

  //...
}
```

If you serialize the container, and deserialize it back, the references should be what you were expecting, because the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream keep references to them while serializing/deserializing your object graph.

### Example:

This works for me:

```
public static void test() {

    class Container implements Serializable {
            Map<String,StringBuilder> map1 = new HashMap<String, StringBuilder>();
            Map<String,StringBuilder> map2 = new HashMap<String, StringBuilder>();
    }

    try(ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("jedis.bin"))){

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("Hello Elvis");

        Container container = new Container();
        //same object in two different maps
        container.map1.put("one", text);
        container.map2.put("one", text);

        out.writeObject(container);

    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("jedis.bin"))) {
        Container container = (Container) in.readObject();
        StringBuilder text1 = container.map1.get("one");
        StringBuilder text2 = container.map2.get("one");

        assert text1 == text2 : "text1 and tex2 are not the same reference";

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, see my answer. An ObjectOutputStream doesn't reset automatically between two sent objects. If you send a single object twice, the second will be a reference to the first one.

Comment: @JB Nizet What you are suggesting in your answer is not at all what I am suggesting. You are suggesting writing two different objects to the the outputstream, I am suggesting writing a single object which is the container of both.

Comment: This answer is suggesting that a single object belonging to multiple object graphs cannot be serialized in such a way that its identity is preserved when deserialized which, as JB points out, is incorrect. Change "You need a container" to "You can use a container" and it's OK.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: your answer still suggests that Java has no way to know that both objects are the same, which is still wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From: [Security in Object Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/security.html):

> ***The serialization package cannot be used to recreate or reinitialize
>   objects. Deserializing a byte stream may result in the creation of new
>   objects***, but will not overwrite or modify the contents of existing
>   objects.

Also - having outside reference and modifying the object state using that (instead of getting reference from the Map) is a bad idea.